# Different rendering between chloroplethr package and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, geospatial, choropleth

I got a visualisation problem and I can't get my head around. From some data with position information included I want to create a map. I found the great `choroplethr` package which was a great starting point and it really helped me a lot to understand how to process data for meaningful results. Here is the map the way I would like to have it:
[image: Figure with choroplethr]

But when I try to replicate the steps (cf. `self$render` of the `chlorplethr` package using `ggplot2`) I get the following result:
[image: Figure with ggplot2]

Does anyone have an idea where my parameters are wrong/lacking something? Here is the code:

```
fig <- ggplot(data=merge.shp, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
    geom_polygon(aes(fill = sqm_cat), na.rm=FALSE, rule="evenodd", position="identity") +
    coord_equal() +
    scale_fill_brewer("", drop = FALSE, na.value = "black") + 
    ggplot2::theme_void() +
    ggtitle("People per square kilometers")
```

Edit: I think, I found the problem. If I just plot the map for one region

```
merge.shp %>% filter(plz %in% c("645")) 
        %>% ggplot(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) + geom_path
```

I get the following result:

[image: geom_path results]

So everything may be related to the "wrong" connection of coordinates. If I replace `geom_path` with `geom_point` there are some reasonable outlines. But how do I translate this to the map?

Comment: I can't test at the moment, however try `coord_map()` instead of `coord_equal()`.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but that didn't work. I have edited the question with new aspects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is actually quite simple. The order is essential for `geom_polygon` and I was mistakenly assuming my dataframe `merge.shp` was in an ascending order for all factors, which it wasn't. Introducing

```
merge.shp = merge.shp[order(merge.shp$order), ]
```

made it work.